# Jasmine spies on nonexistent objects

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, jasmine

I have a backbone router that has the following action:

```
index: ->
  @collection = new App.Collections.ThingsCollection()
  @collection.fetch success: ->
    # ...
```

And I am trying to test this function with Jasmine using a test that looks like this:

```
it 'fetches the collection from the server', ->
  @router.index()
  expect(@router.collection.fetch).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

The difficult occurs when trying to create a spy for `@router.collection.fetch()`. Because `@router.collection` doesn't exist until the `@router.index()` function is actually called, I can't create a spy like this...

```
@fetchStub = spyOn(@router.collection, 'fetch')
```

...because `@router.collection` doesn't yet exist. I haven't put the construction of `@collection` in an `initialize()` function, because it seems unnecessary to have it around for functions that don't use it, such as `new()`. There's probably a well-known solution to this, but I've been unable to find one. Any help would be appreciated.

### Update

This is how I've solved it so far, but a more elegant solution would be nice.

```
  initialize: ->
    @collection = new App.Collections.ThingsCollection()

  index: ->
    if @collection.models.length > 0
      # Assumes @collection.fetch() has already been called (i.e. switching between actions)
      view = new App.Views.ThingsIndex(collection: @collection)
      $('#app-container').html(view.render().el)
    else
      # Assumes @collection.fetch() has not been called (i.e. a new page view or refresh)
      that = this
      @collection.fetch success: ->
        view = new App.Views.ThingsIndex(collection: that.collection)
        $('#app-container').html(view.render().el)
```

So that I can have the following spec:

```
describe 'App.Routers.ThingsRouter', ->
  beforeEach ->
    @router = new App.Routers.ThingsRouter
    @fetchStub = spyOn(@router.collection, 'fetch')

  it 'fetches the collection from the server', ->
    @router.index()
    expect(@fetchStub).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

Answer (score 0):

What about, in your `before` function:

```
@router.collection = new App.Collections.ThingsCollection()
```

There's more related info [here](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/jsdoc/symbols/jasmine.Spy.html#andReturn).

Comment: `@router.collection` gets recreated in the `index()` function, so this wouldn't actually do anything.